# Understanding streams: how does this function work?

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

Consider the following function:

```
template <class T>
void to_string(const T& val, string& s) {
    ostringstream o;
    o << val;
    s = o.str();
}
```

I'm not sure how this function works. I have two assumptions, please tell me which one is correct (if any):

1. `ostringstream` has an overload of `operator<<` that takes whatever `T` is (unlikely).
2. There's a global function with the signature `ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, Sometype& t)`. This allows a `T` to be written to the `ostringstream`, assuming it's a `Sometype`.

Which one of these is more likely correct? I'm assuming the second one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Read the documentation and find out

Answer (score 3):

For some types (most arithmetic ones) there is a [member function `operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) in `ostream`.

For all other types `operator<<` must be a non-member function with the exact signature that you proposed in your second bullet. Although the second parameter is `SomeType const&` in most (if not all) cases.